# Vim jumplist is not updated by <ctrl-o>

Tags: vim, dbext

Pressing `<ctrl o>` does not update the jumplist (evidenced by `:jump`). Jumping to `count <ctrl o>`, e.g. `10<ctrl o>` opens the correct jump, however, this also does not update the jumplist nor moves the jump pointer to a new location.

The following plugins are installed: 
ctrlp.vim
dbext_2000
loremipsum
vim-sensible
vim-surround
vim-unimpaired
vimroom
pathogen.

Also, removing dbext_2000 restores the jumplist updating. Any ideas or experience solving this issue?

Comment: Also, after jumping with `count <ctrl o>` into another file, next `<ctrl o>` actually changes the jumplist, but only within this new file, and the pointer is moved in the jumplist. Using `<ctrl i>` then moves back in. Using `<ctrl i>` after `count <ctrl o>` jumping into another file rings error bell and nothing happens.

Comment: If you can reproduce this with just the dbext_2000 plugin installed, please contact the author; the plugin seems to be well maintained.

Comment: Did just write to the author. Referred him to this question here, so not to repeat myself. Will update with his response, or delete this question here, as the community here will advise.